# Small Prolog Interpreter in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm implementing a small Prolog interpreter in Haskell, I have 
achieved datatypes till now which are:

1. a `Term` which may be a variable or a constant
2. a `Predicate` which has a list of `Term`s
3. `Goals` which is a list of `Predicate`s
4. `Rule` which has a body of type `Predicate` and a list of `Goals`.
5. `Solution` which is `Yes` and the correct unification of variables 
   or `No`.

Now what I'm asking is how can I make a function that takes
two predicates and do the unification between them and return 
an answer of type `Solution`?

Here is my Code:

```
data Term = Cons String |Var String deriving(Show)

data Predicate = Predicate String [Term] deriving(Show)

data Goals = Goals [Predicate] deriving(Show) 

data Rule=Rule Predicate Goals deriving(Show)

data Solution =Yes [(Term,Term)]|No deriving(Show) 

notEqual  a b =a/=b

isCons (Cons _) = True
isCons _=False

isVar (Var _) =True
isVar _=False

bindTerms (y:ys) [] acc=No
bindTerms [](x:xs) acc=No
bindTerms [] [] acc=acc
bindTerms (x:xs) (y:ys) acc|isVar x && isCons y = bindTerms xs ys acc++(Var x,Cons y)
                                                           |isCons x&&isVar y   =bindTerms xs ys acc++(Var y,Cons x)
                                                           |isCons x&& isCons y &&x==y =bindTerms xs ys acc++(Cons x,Cons y)


unify( Predicate a (x:xs)) (Predicate b (y:ys))= if( notEqual a b )then No
                                                                        else if( bindTerms (x:xs) (y:ys))/=No then Yes bindTerms (x:xs) (y:ys)
```

Now what I got is an error due to layout saying

> Syntax error in expression (unexpected `}', possibly due to bad
>   layout)

But my main problem is how to get the answer (list of terms) in the accumulator (in `bindTerms` function) is what I wrote correct using `++` or there is another way?

Comment: You have to implement the unification algorithm. If you don't know what that is you probably shouldn't be doing this project.

Comment: I thought first to check that the name is equal then to see that they have the same number of parameters then just unify them as the paramters in the two predicates will be different(given) there won't be the case where one of the terms in the first given predicate equal the other ,but when I started that with that code I added I got errors ! Am I thinking right or not? thanks

Comment: @user3642820, yeah, you're on the right track.  With some finesse it's actually not too much code, but it can take a while to find the right balance.  Nobody gets it right the first time unless they've done it before.  But "I got errors" doesn't help us help you at all; you'll have to include more detail in your question.

Comment: @luqui can you tell me the problem now ,I have edited my question thanks :)

Comment: Your `bindTerms` is not clear whether it is returning a `Solution` or a list.  Also you have many syntax errors; have you gone through LYAH (http://learnyouahaskell.com/) or another tutorial?  You need more foundational practice.  You might also consider going on IRC (channel `#haskell` on freenode.net) for live help.